# Area 51 profile pic different

Tags: discussion, area-51, profile-page, profile-picture

I have noticed that on the [Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) that the profile picture which you have set for other sides is not shown and instead a default one is shown, and that you cannot upload profile pictures in the same way, instead you have to link to some special external site. Why is this? And if it has to be so that it does not share the same profile pictures as the other SE sites where you have an account, at least why does it force you to upload your picture to an external site and then link to there or something? Why does Area51 not work in the same way with this as other sites do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gravatar.com has been around for ages as well. It was chosen back in the day due to its popularity and widespread use.

Area 51 works the same way the rest of the sites *used* to work. The avatar upload feature is only a couple years old, and it was never ported over to Area 51 - it is a separate codebase, and we are no longer developing new features for it.

Comment: Well, I don't think that you should abandon such an important SE site. Why have you decided not to develop any more features for it? You could at least keep it up-to-date with the rest of the stuff...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda The codebase is so different from current Q&A code at this point that porting over new features from Q&A is basically developing them from the ground up for A51, which we don't have the capacity to do.

Comment: @Adam Are there any plans for a successor site that solves not only technological but also other problems of [area51]?

Comment: @Raphael There sort of used to be, but all that is pretty much shelved indefinitely right now.