# Is there a way to get the same avatar on Area51 as I have on Meta?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-picture

On all the sites I have an account I have the blue avatar, the same as here. But I just noticed that I have a red avatar on Area51. I read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252826/area-51-profile-pic-different) why. Is there a way to get the same avatar on Area51 as I have on Meta? I'd prefer doing this without making Gravatar.